# Obtener la mitad de un arreglo

Tags: php, foreach

Buen día comunidad.
Estoy trabajando en una tabla que muestre el numero de pagos realizados por un cliente, la plabla ya la obtengo sin problemas, lo que necesito hacer es pintar la mitad de los pagos de un lado (izquierda) y la otra mitad del otro (derecha)

éste es mi código:

```
function getTabla($clientes, $entity, $helper)
{
$amortizacion = $entity->getTablaAmortizacionSolidario($clientes);
$total = 0;

$html = '
    <table  cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 9px auto;width:95%;font-size:9px;">
        <thead>
            <tr style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; ">
                <td style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #000;" >Pago No.</td>
                <td style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #000;" >Fecha de Pago</td>
                <td style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #000;" >Monto a Pagar</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>            
        <tbody>';

if (!empty($amortizacion)) {
    foreach ($amortizacion as $val => $row) {

        if ($row['id_cuota'] == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        $html .= '
        <tr style="text-align:center; " >
            <td style="vertical-align:middle; padding:2px; border:1px solid #000;" >' . $row['id_cuota'] . '</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle; padding:2px; border:1px solid #000;" >' . $helper->formateDate($row['fecha_vencimiento']) . '</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle; padding:2px; border:1px solid #000; text-align:right;" >$' .$row['pagos'] . '</td>
        </tr>';

        if ($row['id_cuota'] == 6) {
            $html .= '
            </tbody>
            </table> <br>

            <table cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 9px auto;width:95%;font-size:9px; caption-side: top;">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; ">
                        <td style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #000;" >Pago No.</td>
                        <td style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #000;" >Fecha de Pago</td>
                        <td style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #000;" >Monto a Pagar</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>            
                <tbody>';

        }

        $total += $row['cuota'];
    }
}

$html .= '
        <tr style="text-align:center; " >
            <td style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #000;" colspan="2" ><b>TOTAL A PAGAR</b></td>
            <td style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #000; text-align:right;" >$' . $helper->moneyF($total) . '</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';

$table = '
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <style>
        table{
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .td{
            text-align: center;
            border-style: solid;
            width: 22.5%;
            height: 20px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
     ' . $html . '
</head>
';

return $table;
}
```

Como verán, cuando el numero del pago llega a 6 entonces la tabla termina ahí y empieza a pintar el resto del otro lado, y el número de pagos nunca serán los mismos, por lo que hacer una funsión así no me alludará en la mayoría de los casos..

Agradeceré mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Según he entendido, quieres mostrar la mitad de las filas en una tabla y la otra mitad en otra, y una de las tablas está a la izquierda y otra a la derecha. Si es así, también entiendo que el tema del diseño de las tablas lo tienes ya hecho y se muestran correctamente una al lado de la otra. ¿Es así?

Comment: Si es posible, inserta también una captura de la tabla para ayudarnos a comprender mejor qué necesitas conseguir y tu progreso actual.

Comment: Exacto, pero por ejemplo, si el numero de pagos es de 20 entoces aparecerán 6 de un lado y las otras 14 del otro lado.

Comment: Okey, entonces quieres que en la izquierda aparezcan como máximo las 6 primeras

Comment: no, si son 10 pagos entonces que en la izquierda aparezcan 5 pagos, si son 20 entonces que aparezcan 10 y así sucesibamente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar la funcion `count` de php para obtener el tamaño de tu arreglo y con esto obtienes la mitad de tu arreglo dividiendolo etre dos.

Ejemplo:

```
if (!empty($amortizacion)) {
    $countArray=count($amortizacion);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($amortizacion as $val => $row) {
         if($i<=$countArray/2)//si es la primera mitad, si es impar se muestra aquí 1 más.
         {
         }
         else{//si es la segunda mitad
         }
         $total += $row['cuota'];
         $i++;             
    }
}
```

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, lo checaré.

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código contará cuántos elementos tiene tu array `$amortizacion` y creará 1 nuevo array multidimensional que contendrá otros 2 arrays, cada uno con el contenido de una de las tablas. Se da por hecho que tienes los datos en el array `$amortizacion`:

```
<?php

    //...
    $numFilas = count($amortizacion);

    $amortizaciones = {
        array_slice($amortizacion, 0, ceil($numFilas / 2) - 1),
        array_slice($amortizacion, ceil($numFilas / 2) - 1, $numFilas - 1)
    }

?>
```

En el siguiente código, se imprimirá la siguiente tabla 2 veces, cada una con el contenido respectivo de su array (Está sin estilos):

```
<?php foreach ($amortizaciones as $datosAmortizacion) : ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Pago No.</th>
                <th>Fecha de pago</th>
                <th>Monto a pagar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php foreach ($datosAmortizacion as $row) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $row['id_cuota'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $helper->formateDate($row['fecha_vencimiento']) ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['pagos'] ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Prueba en paiza.io ([Abrir](https://paiza.io/projects/7GZc2PDjd3cdG3vCycIkPA))**

> El código está modificado y tiene contenido de prueba para poder
>   visualizar la tabla con datos de prueba. Debes seleccionar HTML para ver la tabla:

[image: HTML]